# EKS help needed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Need some basic help with EKS. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have a java springboot application as a docker container in ECR.

I created a simple deployment script

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservice-deployment
  labels:
    app: java-microservice
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: java-microservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: java-microservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: java-microservice-container
        image: xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/yyyyyyy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I created a loadbalancer to expose this outside

**loadbalancer.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: java-microservice-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: java-microservice
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

The pods got created. I see they are running

When I do `kubectl get service java-microservice-service`, I do see the loadbalancer is running

When I go to browser and try to access the application via `http://loadbalancer-address`, I cannot reach it.

What am I missing? How do I go about debugging this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does the container work in a plain-Docker setup; can you reach `docker run -p` ports?  Do AWS security groups prevent you from reaching the load balancer?  What's the actual error you get?

Comment: For debugging purposes you could use this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/). If it works it could be something wrong with the container as David Maze mentioned.

Comment: Dawid, I already followed that documentation and the sample application mentioned there (nginx) worked just fine. I had to edit the inbound rules in security group to make it work. For my application, though, the same steps didn't work. David, dn a separate EC2 instance, I can pull the same docker image & it works just fine. Its only when I use the abovementioned deployment and loadbalancer scripts, it doesn't seem to work. If I open a browser and hit the loadbalancer URL, I just get '<loadbalancer> didn’t send any data'

Answer (score 0):

ok. so i changed the port in my yaml files to 8080 and it seems to be working fine.